# How crucial is it that a Bootstrap tutorial be up to date?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, less

I'm enjoying the Bootstrap tutorials [here](http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/complete-websites/twitter-bootstrap-101-introduction/), but after the first two, I realize that it's working off a V1 version of Bootstrap, where the layout worked as a 16-column grid and things like the span-one-third class were still active.

I know I could download and use an old version of Bootstrap, but (a) I'm not that smart, and (b) I'm trying to adopt best practices early on by using a github fork.

I'm not sure what else this tutorial will differ on. I can kind of figure out the differences between a 16- and a 12-column grid, but is there anything in Bootstrap between 1.4 and 2.0 that will completely screw me up while I follow these tutorials?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Super** crucial. There were a significant amount of changes from 1.4 to 2.0, as summarized here: http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/upgrading.html

I would highlight being almost fully responsive as the most important change, but just about any other component has changed, providing better support for mobile devices and keeping up to date with new standards and changes in the industry.

By not upgrading to 2.0 you are limiting yourself from future updates to your framework, as most of the changes *will* break your current progress. Some of the tutorials are good to follow as a "get the idea and implement yourself" tutorial.

Don't stay behind technology just because you are comfortable. You won't be when you have no support for the issues you run into, which are probably fixed in 2.0 or some later version. Save your time now!

Comment: I suppose the follow-up question is obvious: any recommended tutorials for 2.0? I notice that this series has an "introducing 2.0" in it, so I might skip ahead to that, then go back if I have to fill any gaps.

Comment: There are some of them listed here: 
http://www.quora.com/Twitter-Bootstrap/Are-there-any-good-tutorials-on-using-Twitter-Bootstrap